# How to lazy load different routes in Angular5 correctly

Tags: angular, angular5

I am trying to lazy load a module that has children routes. But so far only the   main component keep loading. Here is my lazy loading routes module.

```
export const routes: Routes = [
   { 
    path: '', 
    component: Notfound404Component, pathMatch: 'prefix',
    children: [
      { path: '', pathMatch: 'full', redirectTo: '404' },
      { path: '404', component: Notfound404Component },
      { path: '403', component: Notfound403Component }
    ] 
   }
```

And in my app.routes module I did this :

```
 { path: 'error/403', loadChildren: './errors/errors.module#ErrorsModule'},
  { path: 'error', loadChildren: './errors/errors.module#ErrorsModule'}
```

**Expected behavior** is that `localhost:4200/error` loads the `Notfound404Component` component and `localhost:4200/error/403` loads the `Notfound403Component`

Unfortunately it only loads the `Notfound404Component` on both routes.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: by reading the docs ?

Answer (score 0):

you must put this line to parent route

```
{ path: '', pathMatch: 'full', redirectTo: '/' },
```

and in child route replace

```
{ path: '', pathMatch: 'full', redirectTo: '404' },
```

with this

```
{ path: '', component: Notfound404Component },
```

Answer (score 0):

your routing should be like

**Solution 1:**

```
export const routes: Routes = [
   { 
    path: '', 
    component: Notfound404Component,
    children: [
      { path: '', pathMatch: 'full', redirectTo: '404' },
      { path: '404', component: Notfound404Component },
      { path: '403', component: Notfound403Component }
    ] 
   }
```

**Solution 2:**

```
export const routes: Routes = [
   { 
    path: '', 
    component: Notfound404Component,
    children: [
      { path: '', component: Notfound404Component},
      { path: '404', component: Notfound404Component },
      { path: '403', component: Notfound403Component }
    ] 
   }
```

**NOTE:**  Make sure you create parent component for child route

For eg:  `<router-outlet></router-outlet>`